# Testing a forever running task in asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-asyncio

I need to call a task every second (say) to poll some sensor data on a piece of hardware. In the unit test, all I want to do, is to check that the right methods are called and that errors (such as sensor has blown up or vanished) do get caught.

Here is a *toy* example that mimics the real code:

```
import pytest
import asyncio
import mock


async def ook(func):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        func()


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_ook():
    func = mock.Mock()
    await ook(func)
    assert func.called is True
```

As expected, running this will block forever.

How can I cancel the `ook` task so that the unit test does not block?

A work around would be to split the loop into another function and define it as no testable. I want to avoid doing that.  Note also that messing with `func` (to call `loop.close()` or some such) does not work either as it is there just so the toy example test can assert something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands, the way you've designed the `ook` method is the cause of your issue.

Due to the `ook` method, it will always be a blocking operation. I assume, since you're using `asyncio` you want `ook` to be non-blocking on the main thread?

If thats the case, `asyncio` actually comes with an event loop built in, see [this comment for an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30467159/4996535), which will run an task on another thread and gives you ways to control that task.

Documentation/samples for the event loop are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#event-loop-examples)

Answer (score 3):

Based off [duFF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996535/duff)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45484015/232794), here is the fixed toy code:

```
import pytest
import asyncio
import mock


async def ook(func):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    func()
    return asyncio.ensure_future(ook(func))


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_ook():
    func = mock.Mock()
    task = await ook(func)
    assert func.called is True
    task.cancel()
```

When run:

```
; py.test tests/ook.py
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.1, pytest-3.1.3, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0           
run-last-failure: rerun last 4 failures first                                   
rootdir: /home/usr/blah, inifile: setup.cfg                             
plugins: xvfb-1.0.0, xdist-1.18.2, colordots-0.1, asyncio-0.6.0                 
collected 1 item s 

ook.py::test_ook PASSED

---------- generated xml file: /home/yann/repos/raiju/unit_tests.xml -----------
============================== 0 tests deselected ==============================
=========================== 1 passed in 0.02 seconds ===========================
```